# Download videos from you tube in iOS

Tags: ios, youtube

I want to download you tube videos programatically.I have tried 
**PSYouTubeExtractor** and **XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController** But both are not working in iOS8
Is there any way to download the youtube videos or any way to get the downloadable URLs.
I don't want to upload the app in appstore.

Comment: What do you mean "both are not working?"  What have you tried?  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController has been renamed to [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) and the latest version (2.0.3 as of this writing) works fine on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

**Use LBYouTubeExtractor instead**

https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

```
LBYouTubeExtractor *extractordownload = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc]init];
__block NSURL *urlToReturn = Nil ;

extractordownload=[extractordownload initWithID:videoStr quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];
[extractordownload extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {

}];
```

This will give you a source URL

Download video from this url using AFNetworking or some other way